# Framework (Java) para Abertura de sessões remotas para execução de comandos em Servidor baseado em Unix

Tags: java, shell, framework

Precisava de um `framework` para poder abrir sessões remotas em servidores (baseados em Unix) e executar comandos remotamente (se for possível como `root` mesmo).

Alguém conhece algum e maduro que possa servir para este propósito?

**Principal objectivo:**

O que acontece é que possuo uma aplicação web rodando num servidor e preciso recolher dados em outros servidores. Estes dados são pré-processados num `shell` `script` e guarda os resultados num ficheiro.

São mais de 10 servidores, e seria excelente/ideal que a execução deste `script` em cada um dos servidores fosse feita a partir da aplicação, em vez de executa-lo máquina por máquina e depois a partir da aplicação ler o resultado. A ideia é de abrir uma sessão para cada uma das máquinas e executar o pré-processamento e depois ler os resultados.

**O que tenho:**

De momento utilizo o `jsch` `0.1.42` e tem me dado um problema grave, não consigo executar scripts existentes no servidores cujo algumas operações envolvem escrita(criação de novos ficheiros) no sistema.

**Nota:** O meu principal problema de momento é que a execução do  `jsch 0.1.42` não corre com sucesso, mais quando entro diretamente na máquina ele executa perfeitamente.

Quanto a permissões eu também já analisei e para remover dúvidas as permissões é de tudo para todos(777).

Creio (espero que não seja fruto do meu desespero) que o problema está com o  `jsch 0.1.42` e gostaria de mudar e partir para outro, onde alguém já tem alguma experiência.

Answer (score 1):

Já usei o `jsch` para fazer *build* e *deploy* remoto. Infelizmente não tenho o código-fonte pois foi numa empresa em que não trabalho mais.

O que posso dizer é que ele funciona, mas é muito complicado. Foi uma boa parte de tentativa e erro, alguns ajustes relacionados ao *encoding*, incluindo modificações no próprio fonte do projeto.

Não recomendo esse tipo de solução.

Se fosse implementar algo desse tipo hoje, provavelmente:

1. Faria uma aplicação simples com um Web Service Rest que escuta numa determinada porta, executa os comandos necessários e retorna as informações.
2. Usaria outra linguagem com bibliotecas mais modernas, como Ruby ou Pyhton.

Caso precisa mesmo ser um cliente SSH, usaria provavelmente Python, já que parece haver [várias implementações do protocolo para esta linguagem](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell).

Como foi mencionado que as informações seriam lidas por uma aplicação, é importante considerar questões de *timeout* e paralelização. A aplicação pode usar threads diferentes para realizar uma requisição ao web service (ou SSH).

Deve haver um controle central para não fazer o usuário esperar "pare sempre" em caso de falha e também para garantir que não se acumulem conexões bloqueadas por alguma falha de comunicação (principalmente no caso de SSH).

Comment: Pois é @utluiz, a questão é que não dá pra aplicar a primeira solução pois é um servidor sensível(muitoooo sensível) e os donos não vão aceitar nada lá rodando a mais, com certeza. O segundo ponto é interessante, porém não domino muito dessas linguagens,e até aprender e refazer quase tudo o que já fiz seria "maçoso". Estou a cogitar em usar Pyhton.